# pigpio gpiosetAlertFunc keep missing pulses that are measly 150Hz

Tags: gpio, pi-4, pigpio

I am using pigpio's gpiosetAlertFunc() to listen for a falling edge on a pin but it keeps missing like 80% of the pulses. the pulses are 400ns long that repeats every ~7ms. Im guesing that the pulses are so short for it to detect.

I Increased the sampling rate of the library to the highest possible, it was able to capture more but still not all all of them only 372/600 (~5 seconds)

```
void aFunction(int gpio, int level, uint32_t tick)
{
    if(!level)
    interruptCount++;
}


int main()
{
    gpioCfgClock(1,1,0);
    gpioInitialise();
    gpioSetAlertFunc(13,aFunction);
    delay_ms(5000);
    gpioTerminate();
}
```

something is wrong as the pi should have no problem with these sampling rates

Comment: did you connect the grounds?

Comment: @jsotola yes of course , vcc,ground and signal pins are all connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [gpioSetAlertFunc](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetAlertFunc).  Do the maths to work out how often a 400 nanosecond pulse will be picked up.

For short pulses use [gpioSetISRFunc](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetISRFunc).  That will pick up pulses a few nanonseconds long.